# Why does calling `command -v` in subprocess.run() raise a FileNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

If I run `command` from `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`, I get a similar result:

```
nico@xantico:~$ command -v lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
nico@xantico:~$ sh
$ command -v lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
$
```

(return codes are 0 each time).

If I run it from python, it looks like I need to use `shell=True`, though I do not understand why:

```
nico@xantico:~$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess

>>> subprocess.run('command -v lualatex', shell=True)
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
CompletedProcess(args='command -v lualatex', returncode=0)

>>> subprocess.run('command -v lualatex'.split())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'command'
```

Most suprisingly it raises a `FileNotFoundError`, instead of a `subprocess.CalledProcessError`.

Adding either or both of `text=True` and `check=True` does not change anything.

Using something else as `command` does work as expected (either a `CompletedProcess` with a `returncode` of `0`, or a `subprocess.CalledProcessError`). I've tried with `printf`, `echo`, `ls`, `cat`, `which`...

So, what is so special with `command`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command` is a built-in keyword for `bash` and other shells. Most likely, your system has no actual `/usr/bin/command` executable in its search `PATH`.

`subprocess.run('command -v lualatex', shell=True)` is roughly equivalent to `subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', 'command -v lualatex'])` on systems with the `bash` shell as default. Then `bash` will interpret `command` as its built-in version instead of the system executable version.

`subprocess.run(['command', '-v', 'lualatex'])` on the other hand tries to directly call the system's `command` executable, which isn't there, so `FileNotFoundError`. The actual sub-process was never spawned at all in this case, since there's no executable to call.

From comments below, it appears that you may need to use `shell=True` to use `command` on your system. This is generally considered unsafe for multiple reasons. However, you can mitigate *some* of the risks (e.g. of basic injection) by properly escaping the arguments you send in with `shlex.join`. The `shlex.join` function converts a list of arguments (first one is command name) to a string that's safe for use with `shell=True`; it ensures that the right escaping and quoting is done:

```py
import subprocess, shlex
subprocess.run(shlex.join(['command', '-v', 'lualatex']), shell=True)
```

Comment: OK, that's right: from either `bash` or `sh`, on my system, `which echo` does return a path, `which command` does not. Yet `type echo` and `type command` both return that they're builtins. So it looks like it is possible that a builtin is available from a shell (either `sh` or `bash`), without any actual executable. So if I want to use `command` from python, I do need the `shell=True`.

Comment: And, I've found two other builtins examples that do not have actual executables: `cd` and `exit`.

Comment: Indeed, there is an external `echo` because POSIX requires it, but `command` relates to the shell itself, and so does not make sense to have as an external utility. Similarly, `cd` in a subprocess can't meaningfully change the directory of the calling process, so that's only available as a shell builtin, too.